# Response from website doesn't contain elements I'm trying to find using Xpath and Scrapy. However using ChroPath they are there

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

When I open inspect mode in the browser I can find these elements(href), also if you use ChroPath you can see exact list of links you need with no problem.

I'm trying to take hrefs from these elements:

```html
<a data-ng-bind="::championship.countryName+', '+championship.name + ' '" data-ng-href="/stavki/sport/mma/ufc/dana_white_s_contender_series__season_5__week_10/" class="ng-binding" href="/stavki/sport/mma/ufc/dana_white_s_contender_series__season_5__week_10/">UFC, Dana White's Contender Series: Season 5, Week 10 </a>
```

When I'm trying to get html response using Scrapy or Beautiful Soap, this response doesn't contain these tags, and I can't find element using same Xpath(in ChroPath I can).

Comment: Probably the elements are created dynamically by JavaScript code. Selenium may help.

Comment: It's created dynamically with JavaScript. Open devtools->network->xhr and get it from 'https://winline.ru/api/v2/menu/search?id_project=5&menu_status=1'

Comment: Thank you, guys  I had suspicion about it. Is there any way I can do it without Selenium? @MichaelButscher

Comment: checked and it goes from web socket so in this case there is no way to parse it using standard methods in Scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

checked and it goes from web-socket so in this case there is no way standard   way to take data using Scrapy. Possible to use websocket client but this is another question.